# Parallel inference for different types using TensorFlow to minimize the running time

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to use TensorFlow 2.10 to make inference on 3 different types of data. The pseudo code of my task is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import other libraries

def data_preprocessing(type_i):
    # self-defined function for 
    # getting the test data
    data = ...
    return data

def save_pred(pred):
    # save the prediction results to parquets
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    type_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    for type_i in type_list:
        data = data_preprocessing(type_i)
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_for_type_i) # load model for type_i
        pred = model(data)
        save_pred(pred)
```

In general, for each type, we generate the testing dataset, predict the results using that data, and then finally save the results. Currently, the program runs sequentially for each type (A->B->C), so the total program running time is (almost) the summation of time of running A, B and C (A+B+C). My question is: **How can I modify the codes so that the total time will be approximately the maximum running time of A, B or C?**. I am currently only using CPUs for inference.

I have tried using `multiprocessing`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing
import other libraries

def data_preprocessing(type_i):
    # self-defined function for 
    # getting the test data
    data = ...
    return data

def save_pred(pred):
    # save the prediction results to parquets
    ...

def process_type(type_i):
    data = data_preprocessing(type_i)
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_for_type_i) # load model for type_i
    pred = model(data)
    save_pred(pred)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    type_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(process_type, type_list)
```

However, it seems that the total time does not shrink (almost the same as without using `multiprocessing`).

I also tried `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, but I cannot get the whole results in this way.

BTW, I will pack the codes using pyinstaller, so I guess some libraries like `ray` may not work in this case.